# How do I host a site in Appharbor using github deploy?

Tags: github, appharbor

I deployed a github application in AppHarbor and the AppHarbor built the bridge between them, but it´s not working. When I access the hostname of my app (http://cesarmvcapp.apphb.com/) it only shows me the text "Welcome to nginx!". What do I need to do to make it work?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the application dashboard to confirm that any builds have been received or deployed? The dashboard is here: https://appharbor.com/applications/cesarmvcapp

You may have to push to GitHub to get anything built. Or consider running through the setup flow again.